Near-shore bathymetry contours of a QGIS map
I have created a QGIS map and I am currently attempting to represent the nearshore bathymetry and depth contours. Unfortunately, I am facing an issue where I cannot get different depth colours for the nearshore bathymetry, as they all appear in one colour. I have tried to modify the colour scale, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. It appears that the geodata I have downloaded recognise nearshore bathymetry as one main colour. There is a way to get a differentiation in colour for the nearshore depths?
Thanks

I attempted to modify the scale bar found in the property tab for the raster layer. I used QGIS
